# C++ Friend-like construct for Rust

Tags: rust, encapsulation

In certain cases I would like to leverage whatever alternative there is in Rust to C++'s `friend` keyword. In crate **A** I have the following modules:

**mod a0**:

```
pub struct A {
    pub a0: u8,
    a1: SomeType,
}

impl A {
    pub fn fa0(...) { ... }
    fn fa1(...) { ... }
}
```

Modules `b0` and `c0` need access to all public and private members of `A`. Code cannot do that unless it is in `mod a0`. I want to expose only `A`, `A::a0` and `A::fa0` to other crates interfacing with this crate, but within this crate I want access to the complete implementation of `A` (public and private).

I usually end up doing something like:

**mod a0**:

```
pub struct A {
    pub a0: u8,
    inner: Inner
}

pub struct Inner { /* all pub fields */ }

pub fn get_inner<'a>(obj: &'a mut A) -> &'a Inner {
     &mut obj.inner
}
```

Modules `b0` and `c0` access `get_inner` and hence `Inner`, while in `lib.rs` I do:

```
mod a0;
mod b0;
mod c0;

pub use a0::A; // so other crates cannot use get_inner(...) etc.
```

This seems very convoluted and I seem to be missing something. Or is this the only way to do it ?

Comment: Not possible yet. Wait for [RFC 1422](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1422) to solve this issue.

Comment: The RFC 1422 was [accept](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1422#issuecomment-199443868) on 21 Mar 2016.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Now [RFC 1422](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1422) has been accepted, this is possible! You can replace `pub` in structure definitions with:

- `pub(crate)` to allow access within the current crate
- `pub(super)` to allow access to the current module's parent as well
- `pub(in some_module)` to allow access from `some_module`

Comment: Ah brilliant .. will try out

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, it's possible to make something public, and then hide in from documentation with `#[doc(hidden)]`. Hidden bits are supposed to be not a part of the API, etc. and generally people won't use them anyway since they rely on docs and examples.